# How to use regular expressions word boundary for exact match?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `"Volcano - V3 (2010-2020) blah blah TheVolcano - V3 (2010-2020)"`. I am trying to search search only `Volcano - V3 (2010-2020)`.
I used word boundary in the regex as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = "Volcano - V3 (2010-2020) blah blah TheVolcano - V3 (2010-2020)"
>>> regex = r'\bVolcano - V3 (2010-2020)\b' # '\\bVolcano - V3 (2010-2020)\\b'

>>> re.search(regex, pattern, re.IGNORECASE) # No match!
```

I thought escaping special characters could help and also tried

```
regex = rf'\b{re.escape("Volcano - V3 (2010-2020)")}\b' # '\\bVolcano\\ \\-\\ V3\\ \\(2010\\-2020\\)\\b'
```

but no luck. I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you print the regex to find out what you hand to the engine ? I mean why guess and hope ? Why multi layers of obfuscation ? It's not the engines fault ?

Comment: This re should match: `r"Volcano - V3 \(2010-2020\)"`

Comment: @sln I added the text.

Comment: You search for `Volcano - V3 (2010-2020)` and it requires word boundaries `\b`. Have you tried `\bVolcano[ ]-[ ]V3[ ]\(2010-2020\)\b` ?

Comment: Your first regex is an f-string, but without any use of f-features. Although there is a closing brace that has no counter part. Please fix.

Comment: @trincot; Ya, you are right. Typical copy paste.

Comment: @sln LoL. Actually I didn't get what you mean by "regex thing"?

Answer (score 0):

There are these issues in your first regex:

- The parentheses have a special meaning in regexes, so they should be escaped (since you mean *literal* parentheses should be matched).
- There is no word break between a closing parenthesis and a space, so `)\b` does not match anything in your input string. It would match if your input string had `")A"` in it (for example), but since it only has `") "` there is no match. So drop that `\b`. As you already require the closing parenthesis it is already clear that the "word" 2020 had stopped.

With those fixes it will find a match:

```
import re
pattern = "Volcano - V3 (2010-2020) blah blah TheVolcano - V3 (2010-2020)"
regex = r'\bVolcano - V3 \(2010-2020\)'

print(re.search(regex, pattern, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Note that `search` will only return the first match. If you want to get all matches, then use `findall` or `finditer`.

If your regex is dynamically set, and it might or might not need the `\b` at the front/end, depending if there is a "word" to be matched at the very start/end, then do like this:

```
import re
pattern = "Volcano - V3 (2010-2020) blah blah TheVolcano - V3 (2010-2020)"
target = 'Volcano - V3 (2010-2020)'  # Some dynamically determined literal string
# escape it
regex = re.escape(target)
# check if \b needs to be added
if regex[0].isalnum():
    regex = r"\b" + regex
if regex[-1].isalnum():
    regex += r"\b"

print(re.search(regex, pattern, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: I can't post the actual code unfortunately so yes, your guess is right. I fixed those issues.